# Laravel AngularJS Protractor - chrome browser doesn't launch while testing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, protractor

And I'm running Laravel AngularJs in [dockervel](http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html) docker environment .

I'm using this docker image for protractor https://hub.docker.com/r/webnicer/protractor-headless/.  I have pulled the image in MyApp/e2e_test folder and I have there spec.js and conf.js files.

**spec.js**

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should fill the form', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost/');
    browser.debugger();
    //browser.pause();
    element(by.model('user1Data.name')).sendKeys('haja');
    element(by.model('user1Data.email')).sendKeys('haja@ds.com');
    element(by.model('user1Data.phone_number')).sendKeys('12345');
    element(by.id('register')).click();

    expect(element(by.id('thank')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true); 

  });
});
```

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

console autput:

```
docker run -it --privileged --rm --net=host -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -v $(pwd):/protractor webnicer/protractor-headless conf.js
[20:43:27] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[20:43:27] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[20:43:28] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.69:34981/wd/hub
Started
.



1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 3.843 seconds
[20:43:40] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[20:43:40] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[20:43:40] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

CHROME BROWSER DOESN'T APPEAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. All and everything is working as advertised!

Why?

Headless means there is no (real) display at all. More percisely: It is a virtual in-memory display.

If you really must look at the display, look for Docker images that provide VNC access.